# How can I have this Graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How could I have the similar graph as the graph below in R.
[image: GraPH]

The data set format is

```
Ld.L  2.5
Ld.p  2
Ap.n  0.67
Ap.m  1.5
...
```

Collumn 1 is variables (e.g., Ld.L) and collumns 2 is doffirences

Comment: in base r, you could `plot(tmp <- rnorm(10), rev(tmp), pch = NA); text(tmp, rev(tmp), labels = letters[1:10])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be that you want to add another column for `variable` to specify position on x-axis. The following sample data has three columns.

```
foo <- data.frame(letters = c("Ld.L", "Ld.p", "Ap.n", "Ap.m"),
                  variable = c(5, 10, 7, 1),
                  difference = c(2.5, 2, 0.67, 1.5),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#  letters variable difference
#1    Ld.L        5       2.50
#2    Ld.p       10       2.00
#3    Ap.n        7       0.67
#4    Ap.m        1       1.50
```

If you use `ggplot2`, you could do something like this.

```
ggplot(data= foo, aes(x = variable, y = difference, label = letters)) +
geom_text(size = 6)
```

[image]

If you have the names as rownames, you could do something like this.

```
foo2 <- data.frame(variable = c(5, 10, 7, 1),
                  difference = c(2.5, 2, 0.67, 1.5))

rownames(foo2) <- c("Ld.L", "Ld.p", "Ap.n", "Ap.m")

ggplot(data= foo2, aes(x = variable, y = difference, label = rownames(foo2))) +
    geom_text(size = 6)
```